# What group does one have to be member of to add new User Stories and Bugs on the board?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Currently users are members of the Project Administrators group.

Is that the minimum group membership required to add new User Stories and Bugs to the Boards interface?

Comment: Is there way to limit access to one or more Areas of a Project on the board?  Or do users have access to all Areas of a given project?

Comment: You could also configure the permission on Area level for a project. Details please see my update part in below reply.

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

Area path permissions let you grant or restrict access to edit or modify work items, test cases, or test plans assigned to those areas. You can restrict access to users or groups. You can also set permissions for who can add or modify areas or iterations for the project.

You define both areas and iterations for a project from the **Project Settings>Work>Project configuration**.

1) Choose (1) Project Settings, expand Work if needed, and choose (2) Project configuration and then (3) Areas.

[image]

2) Choose the ... context menu for the node you want to manage and select Security.

[image]

[image]

More details please take a look our official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path).

---

This is not only based on which group you are in.

> ***Note:***
>
> Limitations to select features are based on the access level and
>   security group to which a user is assigned. The Basic access level and
>   higher supports full access to all Azure Boards features. Stakeholder
>   access level provides parti

So to add new User Stories and Bugs on the board, you need to meet both **permissions** and **access** for Azure Boards.

**For Permission:**

Boards present work items as cards and support quick status updates through drag-and-drop.

[image]

You could also use single permission to restrict users with Agile Boards. For if you want a simply solution, you could add them to **Contributors** Group directly.

*Note:* According to Azure DevOps permission setting, most groups and almost all permissions, Deny trumps Allow. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to Deny, that user will not be able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to Allow.

**For Access Level:**

*Agile boards*

Includes limited access to Kanban boards. Stakeholders can't add work items, can't drag-and-drop work items to update status, and can't update fields displayed on cards.

[image]

Conclusion: The minimum should be Contributors Group and Basic Access Level

Answer (score 0):

No, the **Contributors** permissions it's enough:

[image]

More info about the board/work items permissions you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/permissions-access-boards?view=azure-devops).

Comment: One note to add is that depending on users' access level assigned to them (like if they're a Stakeholder), they may not be able to do certain things specifically on the boards. See the Agile Boards feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) it also mentioned in the link I provided.